# Finding string when search string has white spaces

Tags: c++, string

have following code

```
std::string str = "stack overflow=Ask Questions";
size_t pos = str.find("stack overflow");

if(pos != string::npos)
cout << "found" << endl; //works as expected

size_t pos1 = str.find("stack Notflow");
if(pos1 != string::npos)
cout << "found" << endl; //this is printed
else
cout << "NOt found" << endl;
```

In above code how "stack Notflow" is found? How can I get it corrected?

Comment: Works fine for me. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01e560e605bfacbe

Comment: [couldn't reproduce](https://ideone.com/TijiCF). Please provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

You are testing based on `pos` wheras `pos1` stores the result of `str.find("stack Notflow")` either use

`pos = str.find("stack Notflow");` or

`if(pos1 != string::npos)`

for the line `size_t pos1 = str.find("stack Notflow");`

or the one after it.

**EDIT** your edited version works perfectly (at least when I tested it)

Comment: if the orginal version did contain this mistake, it should be rolledback. However, for some reason I dont see that the question was edited.

Comment: @tobi303 I swear it did... strange...

Comment: @tobi303 I saw it too as I was about to point out the exact same mistake Isaac pointed out in his answer.

Comment: in that case I would edit the question. However, I myself will not do it, since I came too late to see the original, but I would suggest you to edit it

Comment: @tobi303 You want me to edit it to make it have the mistake again, and then edit once more to correct it ? (Just so there is a "correct" edit history ?)

Comment: @unda no, the question should be edited to contain the bug (assuming it originally contained it). Asking to fix a bug and then fixing the bug in the question is rather pointless, because then there is no question anymore and given answer become obsolete. Anhow, this question will be closed soon, but imho when the OP is fixing bugs in the question one should insist to keep them, espcially when there are already answers referring to it.

Comment: @tobi303 Alright. Anyway I can't suggest an edit since there's only 1 character to delete. See the second `if` statement was originally `if(pos != string::npos)` (note de `pos` instead of `pos1`)

Comment: @tobi303 as OP simply altered his code without saying anything/accepting an answer I assumed that his changes did not make his code work (but I see no way his corrected code could possible not-work)